# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a Google extension, and among all the problems I had while doing so, I had this problem that I can't figure out how to fix even by looking at soooo much answers in StackOverflow.

Basically, this code is supposed to open a popup that replaces the existing popup when you click on a link in this popup.

So this code, when you click on the "clickme" link, opens "popup2.html". Maybe the answer is obvious, but my javascript knowledges are more than rusty...

```
var hrefs = document.getElementById("clickme");

function openLink() {
    var href = this.href;
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        var tab = tabs[0];
        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: href});
    });
}

for (var i=0,a; a=hrefs[i]; ++i) {
    hrefs[i].addEventListener('click', openLink);
}
document.getElementById('clickme').addEventListener('click', hello);
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Sounds like `tabs` is null.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are accessing the 0 property from the `hrefs` variable, which is null.

```
hrefs[i].addEventListener('click', openLink);
```

Your code assumes `hrefs` holds an array but it is a DOMElement. `i` is 0 in your case. The loop is also an infinite loop I guess.

Comment: I think it's worse. This code assumes that IDs can be non-unique.

Comment: I think I understand now... but is there a way to make the href not null from the beginning, or just telling him to go check "popup2.html" directly?

Comment: If "popup2.html" is your current page and if there is an element on the page with `id="clickme"`, `hrefs` should be filled.